# How can I disable element.style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the `element.style 'margin-left: 0;'` on one of my `ul` classes. I would like to get rid of it but I can't change the js file without messing everything up so I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this in my CSS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you change the js file without messing it up? has it been obfuscated?

Comment: in your css use `margin-left: auto !important`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS just do

```
ul.something {
    margin-left: auto !important; // or whatever px instead of auto
}
```

That will work most of the time, provided it's the last stylesheet to be loaded, otherwise it might be overridden by a different style again.

Comment: I don't think so .. This will never be overridden unless the user targets the element with better specificity and sets that as weel to !important.  Also using important in your CSS is not a good practice.

Comment: It's not good practice, but in this case (as he can't change the JS file), it's the only way I can think of

Comment: sure.. I get that .. May be #container ul.something {
    margin-left: auto ; //  should do 
}

Comment: @Sushanth it won't because if I understand correctly javascript is adding it as inline style which is most important(ofcourse less important than `!important` itself)